# How can I programatically get the MEID/ESN in Bada?

Tags: c++, mobile, samsung-mobile, bada, serial-number

I am trying to gain access to the MEID/ESN using C/C++ on Samsung's Bada OS. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction (websites, documentation, etc).

Thanks much!
-Kamran

Answer (score 0):

Is MEID same as IMEI? The latter can be retrieved via `SystemInfo`:

```
String s;
Osp::System::SystemInfo::GetValue(L"IMEI", s);
```

This is not documented, and possibly will stop working at some point.

Also there's `Osp::Telephony::SimInfo` class which returns a whole bunch of three letter acronyms. See if one of them is what you need.